# JavaFX PerspectiveCamera error

Tags: javafx, 3d, javafx-2, perspectivecamera

I wanna write a code about using `PerspectiveCamera` in JAvaFX
but I always get error when defining new `PerspectiveCamera` with constructor

Here is my a part of my code:

```
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
...
PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(false);
```

but it says:

```
constructor PerspectiveCamera in class PerspectiveCamera cannot be applied to given types;
```

I'm using JavaFX version `2.2.60-ea-b15`

Comment: Which JavaFX version are you using?

Comment: javafx.runtime.version: 2.2.60-ea-b15 @fabian

Answer (score 1):

The constructor you're trying to use was added in JavaFX **version 8**. Therefore it's not available using JavaFX 2.X.

[See javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/PerspectiveCamera.html#PerspectiveCamera-boolean-):

> [...]
>
> **Since:**
>
> JavaFX 8.0

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaFX version is very outdated (Java7 update 60). I am not sure it supports 3D at all. Try to update to a recent version. You also did not mention the system you are running on.